# Why didn't Queen Amidala reveal herself to the Jedi knights earlier in The Phantom Menace?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

If the Queen really trusted the two Jedi knights, why not reveal herself?

Comment: If you watch the movie, you can see that Qui-Gon has already figured it out by the time she revealed herself.  It's also a security measure: if someone doesn't know something, then there is no possibility that they can leak it.

Comment: A vaild point. I see where you're coming from. However, I've been watching the film and, in my opinion, I don't see any indication of Qui-Gon's knowledge of the matter. His personality is sometimes hard to read. I think it's debatable. Also, I'm more of a Trekkie anyway. I didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Nothing to gain; much to lose.

The security arrangement for Naboo queens — not just details, but even the existence of this strategy — was a state secret.  Although Amidala had latitude to disclose it, as she eventually did to earn the trust of Boss Nass, she had nothing to gain by revealing it earlier to the two Jedi, whose cooperation she already had.

Queen Amidala travelled with a contingent of Naboo soldiers and handmaidens/bodyguards, many (most? all?) of whom knew her secret identity.  They were bound by obligation and patriotism to protect her, and Amidala had to act within her prescribed role to avoid complicating their duties and thereby endangering everybody.  The Naboo team would have resented anyone breaking security protocol unnecessarily.

[image: John Lawton, the shrugging Secret Service agent from the JFK motorcade.]

<sup>*Figure 1: The shrugging man in this photo is USA Secret Service agent Donald Lawton, reacting with frustration to an order that in his opinion lessened security effectiveness for President John F. Kennedy during the motorcade in Dallas, shortly before Kennedy's assassination.*</sup>

Comment: Is the implication here that "Donald Lawton" was a false identity used to protect President Kennedy during negotiations with the Gungans?

Comment: not sure how the answer connects with the JFK info...

Comment: @NKCampbell — I thought that an answer based on logical inference rather than on a direct quote from *Star Wars* could use the support of a real-world example of a security officer objecting to a spontaneous lowering of security protocol.

Comment: This security protocol pays off later when an attempt is made on the Padme's life; I'd imagine that the more people you tip off about your decoy, the less likely that is to work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Padme really benefited from her ruse in *Episode I* from a strategic/interpersonal standpoint.

She was able to stay apprised of Qui-Gon's schemes, which would have been more difficult had she remained on her ship, since Qui-Gon purposefully did not keep her decoy in the loop.

Her entire relationship with Jar Jar is possible because of this scheme: They first interact while she's cleaning R2-D2, then they continue to bond while on Tatooine. On Coruscant, Jar Jar talks to the Queen persona, revealing that the Gungans have an army, inspiring Padme's return to Naboo. It's extremely plausible that this interaction is made possible by Padme's incognito time with Jar Jar, giving her a better perspective on Gungans and giving him a comfort level with the Naboo that make him feel comfortable talking to the Queen.

So, there's a real benefit to having an alter ego. People can be duplicitous, or just different around someone in power, so there's a tactical benefit from approaching people as a handmaiden. Padme's reveal to Boss Nass would thus be the exception rather than the rule: it was done when she realized that she had a once-in-a-lifetime shot to mend relations with the Gungans AND free her planet from invasion. If that's true, then it wouldn't be a question of whether she trusted the Jedi.

P.S. I should add: the fact that Sabe orders Padme to clean an astromech droid is either light trolling, or proof that Padme wants to be outside of the room interacting with the crew incognito. The latter seems more likely.